# Apache2 rewrite rules aren't working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I'm trying to remove .html extensions from my urls using this code in .htaccess (code found online).

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

It is not working. I found a post saying to use this to test if mod-rewrite is enabled: `/usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -D DUMP_MODULES | grep rewrite`

It returns:

```
Syntax OK
 rewrite_module (static)
```

Nothing in the error log. This is on a server with WHM and cPanel if it matters. My other .htaccess directives are working.

Comment: can you paste full url from you website with .hmtl included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does the exact opposite of what you are trying to accomplish. The correct code would be:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make a request for an existing html file, these conditions are going to prevent the rule from doing anything:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Because they say, if the requested file doesn't exist and isn't a directory... And when you request an html file, it's going to fail the `-f` test. So rule does nothing.

You want to match against something like the actual request:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /([^.]+)\.html($|\ |\?)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]
```

This redirects a request for an existing HTML file to the same path but minus the extension. You can then rewrite it back internally:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.html [L]
```